# Bash uniq taking newline into account

Tags: bash, line, newline, uniq

For some reason, uniq seem to be recognizing the newline character when comparing different lines, and recognizing the files newline differently than \n (or at least that's what it seems like to me).

What I want it to do is take a file like this:

```
hello world hello hello
meh
hello
hello
```

and get output like:

```
5 hello
1 world
1 meh
```

But my code:

```
x=`sed 's/ /\n/g' $1 | uniq -c | sed 's/      //g'`
echo "$x"
```

is outputting this:

```
1 hello
1 world
2 hello
1 meh
2 hello
```

Comment: "For some reason"? Why is that a surprise? From the man page: `uniq - report or omit repeated lines`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uniq` expects sorted input.

```
$ sed 's/ /\n/g' f | sort | uniq -c | sed 's/      //g'
5 hello
1 meh
1 world
```